# PHP does not pass password to SQL database, but passes everything else in the form like email and username

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a simple registration function, and it works -- the php succeeds in sending the username and email to the database, just not the password. I hope someone can help me.

```
    if(!isset($error)){

        $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

        try {

            //insert into database
            $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO blog_members (username,password,email) VALUES (:username, :password, :email)') ;
            $stmt->execute(array(
                ':username' => $username,
                ':password' => $hashedpassword,
                ':email' => $email
            ));
```

Comment: How/where is `$hashedpassword` set?

Comment: Some error/notice must be being thrown. Can that be shared, and/or can error reporting be enabled if not?

Comment: Also what is the data type of the password in your database.. ?

Comment: Does the `$user` object have a `password_hash` function? ... I would have simply thought: `$hashedpassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`.

Comment: please mention the code where you creating $password variable with $_POST

Comment: Please do `echo $password . "<br>\n";` before hash and `echo $hashedpassword . "<br>\n";` after you hash the password and show us what you have got from these 2 values.